# How do I check a large floating point number to see if it is an integer?

Tags: python, integer

It is not a problem to check a small number for whether it is a float or an integer

```
>>> 4.0.is_integer()
True
>>> 4.123.is_integer()
False
```

```
if a - int(a) == 0:
    print('Integer')
else:
    print('Not Integer')
```

But when I have a large number, it does not work anymore:

```
>>> 31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423.111.is_integer()
True
```

I would like to check very many and very large numbers, and the results of my calculations are floating-point numbers. I want to check if the result is an integer. For large numbers, the conventional methods do not work.

Comment: Check whether the modulo 1 division remainder is zero. Alternatively, integer-divide by 1 and check if it makes a difference.

Comment: For your purpose, is `4.00` an `int` or a `float`?

Comment: I'm unsure, what your input format is. If it is already a Python variable all proposed ways work. If it is text a search for a decimal separator may help.

Comment: @guidot `a - int(a) == 0` is `True` for large floats. It's certainly true for the `b` in the question.

Comment: Why do you say it `.is_integer()` does not work for "laaaarge" numbers? For the given example it worked flawlessly. Can you provide an example that shows the contrary?

Comment: Please don't add "Edit" sections to your question. Overwork it to make it clearer what you want. Also, your latest edit claims that you want `5.243` to be considered as integer!?

Comment: Where do these large values come from, and how are you storing them?  If you are using the standard Python `float` (which is IEEE 754 64 bit floating point), then any value with magnitude greater than `2**52` is an integer.  There are only finitely many numbers representable as 64 bit floating point.  The subset of those numbers greater than 2**52 are integers.

Answer (score 2):

Using floats, it's not possible with numbers of the magnitude shown in your example, because eventually the precision of floating point becomes too coarse to distinguish the integer from the float.  For example:

```
>>> 100000000000000000000000.5 == \ 
... 100000000000000000000000.0                                                                                                                                        
False
>>> 1000000000000000000000000.5 == \ 
... 1000000000000000000000000.0                                                                                                                                       
True
```

Both inputs were parsed to identical numbers.  If you need the granularity to distinguish such values, parse them from strings into a different type such as [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

For high precision *calculations*, you may also be interested in using a multiple-precision arithmetic library such as [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/).

Comment: And to be clear, "get in before the numbers have been evaluated and access the original source" should usually mean "rewrite your source code to stop using floats for this", not "kludge together something with source inspection".

Answer (score 0):

Simply checking type might be misleading. If you're trying to solve a mathematical problem where your function spills continous range of numbers and you want to check which are integers, then `type(a)` likely won't work for you.

Solution: use `is_integer` instead.

```
a = 31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423.0
print('Type: ',type(a))
print('Is integer: ',a.is_integer())
```

The first check gives you `float`, while the other tells the number is integer.

Comment: Its not the Solution

Comment: `31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423.111.is_integer()` is `True`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **isinstance**. Here is example:

```
a = 100
print(isinstance(a, int))
```

It will print **True** or **False** values depends of value type for **a** variable (**True** in this case above).

```
print(isinstance(a, float))
```

In example above it will print **False**

Answer (score 0):

The `length = (int) (math.log10(a) + 1);` will return the length of integer only.

Try it here:
https://onlinegdb.com/Sk1jmeTxV

```
import math
a= 31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423

b = 31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423.111

length = (int) (math.log10(a) + 1);

if length ==len(str(abs(a))): 
   print ('is a perfect int');
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you get the number as string from the input or file, and you can use the decimal module:

```
    import decimal

    ctx=decimal.Context(prec=200)

    b=decimal.Decimal("31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423.111")                                                                                                            

    print( ctx.divmod(b,1) ) 
    Out: Decimal('31231242354234534534534534534534534534534534535434645755453543543453534534534534534535345346756423423'), Decimal('0.111'))

    print(ctx.divmod(b,1)[1].is_zero())    # integer?                                                                               
    Out: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to check if the cube root of a number "x" is an integer.

The result of a root calculation is a floating-point number.

For example, the following numbers "y" should be checked:

```
x = 12341254534XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
y = x**(1/3)  # y = cube root of x

y = 6456535XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.2146544753325
or
y = 6456535XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.0
or 
y = 6456535XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.99999999999646546547
```

This does not work for these large numbers.